# to_sql add column if not exists (sqlalchemy mysql)

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

while appending rows to mysql table with pandas `to_sql` like

```
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append')
```

the appending `df` may contain some new column, which does not exist in mysql `table_name`,

so, I get pymysql.err.InternalError fired:

```
InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'new_columns' in 'field list'")
```

While trying to catch this exception to add `new column` to the mysql table  I cannot catch `pymysql.err.InternalError` exception for some reason, so I try to do it in a weird way with `BaseException` like this:

```
     while True:
         try:
             df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append')
         except BaseException as e:
             b = e.args
            missing_column = b[0].split('(pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column \'')[1].split(' in \'field list\'")')[0].replace("'",'')
            with sql.engine.connect() as con:
                con.execute(f'ALTER TABLE {table_name} ADD COLUMN {missing_column} TEXT;')
        else: break
```

This solution ugly and unstable, so I would appreciate your advice!

Comment: Did you get a good solution?

Comment: No, still using the above

Comment: Just as a side note, you should always pass the arguments to the `execute` function and not the query itself, for security reasons. See -> `con.execute(f'ALTER TABLE :table_name ADD COLUMN :missing_column TEXT;', table_name='test', missing_column='column')`

Answer (score 0):

you can check sql table columns before appending new data to it:

```py
import pandas as pd

target_name = "your_table"
target_cols = pd.read_sql_query(f"select * from {target_name} limit 1;").columns.tolist()
your_cols = df.columns.tolist()

if set(your_cols) - set(target_cols) == set():
# APPEND OPERATION...
else:
# NEW COL OPERATION...
```